# Google Analytics: Source/Medium reports decoding

Tags: google-analytics

I have recently inherited responsibility for an old site and its GA profile.  When looking at the Source/Medium I can see the regular referrals such as Twitter and Google.  But there are some referrers that I don't understand.  Maybe they are custom codes set up by the previous administrator.

Here are some of the results for Source / Medium reports:

- 1 / more
- 2 / 21024
- 2 / 51018

Where can I look to find out more about these referrers in my GA account?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add as a Secondardy dimension *Referral Path*.  It could be helpful.

Probably these *source /medium* comes from custom UTMs defined to track some kind of traffic